# How to run multiple test classes or test methods using Maven?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

In order to run all Maven tests, we can use:

```
mvn clean test
```

If we want to run specific test class, we can use:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=className
```

If we want to run specific method from specific test class, we can use:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=className#methodName
```

But I want to run:

1. multiple test classes(not all that belong to `src\test\java`)
2. multiple test methods from specific test class(not all test methods of specific test class that belong to `src\test\java`)

Are there Maven commands using which I can achieve above two?

Comment: If you are using Surefire plugin you can see the documentation. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: an include/exclude (if using surefire) with a pattern is a possibility (and some profiles)

Answer (score 38):

If using surefire plugin then you may use the below options.

For multiple classes you can use,

```
mvn -Dtest=TestSquare,TestCi*le test
```

For multiple methods in same class you can use,

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#testOne+testTwo test
```

Refer [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

Comment: Thanks Subir for the answer! I can run multiple test classes as you suggested, but I can't run multiple methods in same class as per your suggestion. I've `surefire-plugin 2.18` and `testng 6.8.13`. Both are with latest version.

Comment: Same for me, I get this exception:
JUnit4Provider.invoke:128->executeTestSet:147->getMethod:307 » StringIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: When I try to run the multiple classes command (and only with that) I get the following error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project: No tests were executed!`

Answer (score 14):

You can use wildcards - note that you have to quote the test argument so the shell does not expand the wildcard.

```
mvn -Dtest="TestSquare,TestCi*le" test
```

(using maven-surefire-plugin:2.17)

Answer (score 2):

If You want to launch all test Clases from subdirectory, eg: /doc/ You can use command:

```
mvn -Dtest=*/doc/* test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple classes in TestNG with their groups, like

```
<groups>
  <run>
    <include name = "checkintest" />
    <include name = "videoSpider" />
    <include name = "xmlTCUploader" />
    <include name = "PALLogin" />
  </run>
</groups>
<classes>
  <class name="SeleniumUC"/>
  <class name="PALTestCasesSuite"/>
</classes>
```

After this, you can use these group with Maven like -

```
mvn -Dgroups=PALLogin test
```