# How to run multiple methods present in different classes on mvn command line

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml, testng-eclipse

How to run multiple methods present in different classes on mvn command line
referred [How to run multiple test classes or test methods using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653510/how-to-run-multiple-test-classes-or-test-methods-using-maven) 
doesn't work for multiple method present in different class

Tried with below line
mvn -Dtest=testclass#method1, -Dtest=testclass2#method1 test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple test classes or test methods using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653510/how-to-run-multiple-test-classes-or-test-methods-using-maven)

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html provides a lot of examples, including examples that mix and match different classes and different methods from each class

Comment: @Oleg Estekin suggested link gives the solution to run multiple different classes or multiple methods present in single class. Here want a command to run multiple different classes with their method. For eg., Class A has methods testmethod1(), testmethod2() and Class B has methods testX(),testZ() now I want to run through command line statement contains CalssA methods and ClassB methods