# Is there a way to tell maven which testClass it should execute

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Here's my problem.

I'm using a single project with so many testClass

```
--Package
----TestClass1
----TestClass2
----TestClass3
```

Every `testClass` is a test suite, that contains it's own `beforeTest`, `test` and `afterTest` annotations

I want to implements a number of jenkins jonbs as much as testClass

Now my only dummy solutions is to duplicate project and create a single testClass for each job.

Is there a way to say to maven to point at a class by it's name, or something similar to that ? Someting like `mvn clean test -D=className`

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in the test name as part of the maven params i.e.

-Dtest=TestClass1, TestClass3 test

to run TestClass1 and TestClass3

More examples found @ [How to run multiple test classes or test methods using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653510/how-to-run-multiple-test-classes-or-test-methods-using-maven)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the command line property `surefire.includesFile` to a file, in which you list the relevant classes. See also

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

where you should be looking for "includesFile".

Comment: Thanks
How I can configure my jenkins to execute the right class with surefire ? is there something to add in the execution command ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a TestClass1.xml file for specific Test class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.tutorial.testng.TestClass1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Now use dynamic xml file name in 'maven-surefire-plugin' as mention below.

```
<configuration>

        <suiteXmlFiles>

            <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
         <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>

        </suiteXmlFiles>


</configuration>
```

Now you can utillize run it via maven

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=TestClass1.xml
```

In Jenkins, you can create job with "build with parameters" and create a string parameter. Now you can pass testng.xml in Jenkins. Check below how to do it.

https://www.theserverside.com/video/Modify-CI-jobs-with-this-Jenkins-parameterized-build-example

Hope it will help.